# getActivity() возвращет null

Tags: android, activity, android-fragment

Доброго всем времени суток. Для начала наверное опишу принцип работы приложения.

Приложение состоит из трех активити. Первая показывает прогресс бар, пока приложение загружает необходимые для работы данные, вторая показывается только в случае ошибки получения данных или неработающего интернет соединения (упс! Что то пошло не так), третья основная. Это `DrawerActivity`, в которой все действия осуществляются во фрагментах. У неё есть контейнер (`FrameLayout`), в который фрагменты кладутся. Приложение - интернет магазин, следовательно фрагментов огромное количество. несколько для представления уровней каталога, несколько для разных опций юзера (избранные товары, заказы, авторизация, регистрация, уведомления и т.д.), несколько для разных шагов оформления товаров. То бишь взаимодействие с фрагментами идёт полным ходом. Для него мне нужно постоянно обращаться к активити за фрагмент менеджером. Так же у меня есть некоторое количество своих View, в том числе построенных на xml разметке, для которых мне нужен `LayoutInflater`. Беру я его каждый раз следующим образом `getActivity().getLayoutInflater()`. Есть у активити несколько интерфейсов для различных действий, и опять же, мне надо гетать активити и приводить её к нужному интерфейсу. Как видите обращений к ней крайне много. И некоторые из них провоцируют null. Первый вопрос - почему это может происходить?

На английском стаке прочитал следующий совет. Человек советует унаследовать от `Fragment` собственный класс, например `BaseFragment`,  котором хранить ссылку на активити, и от него наследовать другие фрагментыи получать активити непосредственно по ссылке, так:

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    protected FragmentActivity mActivity;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mActivity = (FragmentActivity) activity;
    }
}
```

Выглядит интересно, но каждый фрагмент будет хранить ссылку на активити, и когда они будут класться в стэк транзакций, не будет ли утечки памяти? Это второй вопрос. Третий вопрос такой - что если объявить ссылку на активити в `BaseFragment` `static`? Ведь в приложении используется с фрагментами только одна активити, первая умирает до того, как в дело идут фрагменты, и выход из приложения производится минуя другие активити, то есть в данном случае утечки удастся избежать. Ссылка будет пстоянной и будет доступна во фрагментах кроме первого даже раньше, чем вызовется метод onAttach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно понимать одну концептуальную вещь.

> Если `getActivity()` возвращает `null`, то фрагмент уже отсоединен от активити. Соответственно производить любые манипуляции с UI уже не имеет никакого смысла. Фрагмент уже не виден пользователю.

Т.е. сохранение ссылки на активити где-либо никогда ни к чему хорошему не приводит. Не нужно это делать, особенно в статическую переменную (мертвая активити может там зависнуть до полной выгрузки приложения из памяти).

Совет один, всегда проверяйте ссылку на активити, если она `null`, то фрагмент свое "отжил" и пора ему "закругляться". Исключение только для обработчиков событий пользователя, тут никто активити "из-под ног" не выдернет :)

А совет с `onAttach()` верный только в случае если в `onDetach()` ссылку на активити занулять. Иначе Вас ждет куча головной боли.

Comment: Спасибо за концептуальную вещь. Большое. Полезные зерна информации очень редко просачиваются сквозь обилие воды)

Comment: Не могли бы поподробнее написать про "Иначе Вас ждет куча головной боли."? Я вот думал, что утечёт активити, если не обнулить ссылку в onDetach, но утечки памяти не возникло.

Comment: @gabber, утечки не будет, если как и автор, сохраняете в нестатическую переменную. Головная боль может начаться, когда фрагмент фактически отсоединится от активити, а ваша ссылка не будет обнулена, соответственно вы можете считать что у вас есть доступ к контексту, а фактически это уже не ваш контекст. Как-то так.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja ну так и подумал да. Хотя по-хорошему, если в onDestroyView отписаться от всего, то никто и не обратится к этому полю. Но все же я с вами согласен, что лучше в onDetach явно занулять ссылку, так сказать от греха подальше))